When using the Python Concurrent Futures should I use ALL the vCores?
Is it safe when using the Python Concurrent Futures to use ALL the vCores available in the machine?
My code currently uses the vCores available minus 1 as I want to leave one vCore "free" for the system, to avoid freezing the system. I am wonder if this approach is silly and if the concurrent futures manages somehow manages this.
def get_cpu_cores():
    """
    Get the number of CPU cores minus one.

    Returns:
        int: Optimal number of threads.
    """
    cpu_count = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    return max(1, cpu_count - 1)


This won't "freeze" the system.  You are thinking that your processes are forced and locked into the CPUs one by one.  That's just not the case.  Your processes go into the scheduler just like all the other processes.  The system will schedule them into CPUs as they become available.
